# How to pass parameters to SSRS report programmatically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services

I'm looking for a little help on programmatically passing parameters to a SSRS report via VB.NET and ASP.NET.  This seems like it should be a relatively simple thing to do, but I haven't had much luck finding help on this.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to go to get help with this, or perhaps even some sample code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do the following,: (it works both on local reports as in Full Blown SSRS reports. but in full mode, use the appropriate class, the parameter part remains the same)

```
LocalReport myReport = new LocalReport();
myReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Path/To/Report.rdlc");

ReportParameter myParam = new ReportParameter("ParamName", "ParamValue");
myReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { myParam });

// more code here to render report
```

Comment: what if im not using local reports but don't want to leave explicit values on the url?

Answer (score 11):

If the Report server is directly accessible, you can pass parameters in the Querystring if you are accessing the repoort with a URL:

http://MyServer/ReportServer/?MyReport&rs:Command=Render&Param1=54321&Param2=product

You can add output formatting by adding the following on the end of the URL:

&rs:Format=Excel

or

&rs:Format=PDF

Comment: Passing the parameters as a URL seems like it opens the door for someone to hack your report.  This might be okay for an internal site, but probably not for a public facing site.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I did this code, but it may help:
Your web project has to be a Web Site, and not a project of type "ASP.Net Web Application", or you won't be able to add the reference mentioned below.
Right click on the project and add an ASP.Net folder - App_WebReferences.  You'll have to specify the server where your SRS is; choose the .asmx.
Once it's added, the folder under that level is called RSService, and under that are 2 things:  reportservice.discomap & .wsdl.
In my VB, I do Imports RSService and Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols, then...

```
Dim MyRS As New ReportingService
```

The reporting service is on a different server than the webserver the app is on, so I can't do the following: `MyRS.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`

Instead:  `MyRS.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(rs1, rs2, rs3)`,
where the rs1/2/3 are the login to SRS box, password to SRS box, & domain name".  (These are encrypted in my web.config.)

Then, a mass-paste:

```
MyRS.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(rs1, rs2, rs3)

Dim ReportByteArray As Byte() = Nothing
Dim ReportPath As String = "/SRSSiteSubFolder/ReportNameWithoutRDLExtension"
Dim ReportFormat As String = "PDF"
Dim HistoryID As String = Nothing
Dim DevInfo As String = "<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>"
'Dim x As ReportParameter - not necessary
Dim ReportParams(0) As ParameterValue
ReportParams(0) = New ParameterValue()
ReportParams(0).Name = "TheParamName"
ReportParams(0).Value = WhateverValue

Dim Credentials As DataSourceCredentials() = Nothing
Dim ShowHideToggle As String = Nothing
Dim Encoding As String
Dim MimeType As String
Dim ReportHistoryParameters As ParameterValue() = Nothing
Dim Warnings As Warning() = Nothing
Dim StreamIDs As String() = Nothing
'Dim sh As New SessionHeader() - not necessary
''MyRS.SessionHeaderValue = sh - not necessary

ReportByteArray = MyRS.Render(ReportPath, ReportFormat, HistoryID, DevInfo, ReportParams, Credentials, _
    ShowHideToggle, Encoding, MimeType, ReportHistoryParameters, Warnings, StreamIDs)
'(Yay! That line was giving "HTTP error 401 - Unauthorized", until I set the credentials
' as above, as explained by http://www.odetocode.com/Articles/216.aspx.)

'Write the contents of the report to a PDF file:
Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(FullReportPath, ReportByteArray.Length)
fs.Write(ReportByteArray, 0, ReportByteArray.Length)
fs.Close()

Call EmailTheReport(FullReportPath)

If IO.File.Exists(FullReportPath) Then
    IO.File.Delete(FullReportPath)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.Reset();
Label1.Visible = false;
ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet = new ClassBLL().Load_Report_Detail(TextBox1.Text, 
ddlType.SelectedValue, levelcode, fields);
ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet_StoreprocedureName",
dataSet.Tables[0]);

if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
{
    ReportViewer1.Visible = false;
}

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("") + @"\Report.rdlc";
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
string fields="name,girish,Z0117";
string[] filedName = fields.Split(',');
ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[2];

//for (int i = 0; i < filedName.Length; i++)
//{

param[0] = new ReportParameter(filedName[0], filedName[0], true);
param[1] = new ReportParameter(filedName[3], filedName[3], true);

// }


ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);

ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: The question specifically asks for VB, you offered C#.